# Export PDF/A from mathematica

Tags: plotting, export, latex

I want to paste my plots from Mathematica into LaTeX which creates PDF/A. If I use any greek letters on axis labels the result is no more valid PDF/A.

If I export the plot as png it gets a little blury. With jpeg it is insanely blury.

Comment: You could set the `CompressionLevel->0` to get a higher quility jpg. Also look at `ImageResolution`

Comment: Did you try to opne the LatTex generate PDF in Adobe Reader?

Comment: @Gopal Verna - I did open it in Adobe.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I finally decided to export Mathematica plot to PDF without labels and add them in LaTeX.